# NGRX returns success before throwing error

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am throwing an exception in my service and trying to catch the exception in my effect and return the correct toast on the frontend.

**What happens**:  It looks like i get a success message and then an error is thrown, i see the error in the console but never the "Error" toast on the frontend.  I put a breakpoint on the catcherror line in the service.  I see the success toast before the breakpoint gets hit.

**What should happen**:  Should show the "Error" toast on the frontend after catching the error.

Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

**Service**

```
saveBusiness(business: BusinessModel) {
    return from(this.businessCollection.add(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(business)))).pipe(
      catchError(err => throwError(err))
    );
  }
```

**Effect**

```
AddBusiness$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(BusinessActions.AddBusiness),
      mergeMap(({ business }) =>
        of(this.businessService.saveBusiness(business)).pipe(
          map(() => BusinessActions.CreateBusinessSuccess()),
          catchError(() => of(BusinessActions.CreateBusinessFailure()))
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

**Action**

```
export const CreateBusinessFailure = createAction(
  '[Business] Failed Creating to database'
);
```

**Component Snippet**

```
actions$
      .pipe(ofType(BusinessActions.CreateBusinessSuccess))
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.notifyService.showSuccess(
          'Business was saved successfully',
          'Success'
        );
      });
    actions$
      .pipe(ofType(BusinessActions.CreateBusinessFailure))
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.notifyService.showError(
          'Business was not saved. Please check the information and try again',
          'Failed creating business'
        );
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to catch the error in the service just to throw it again:

> ```
> saveBusiness(business: BusinessModel) {
>     return from(this.businessCollection.add(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(business)))).pipe(
>       catchError(err => throwError(err))
>     );
>   }
> ```

The effect will catch the error (assuming is "add" or JSON.parse throwing the error:

```
saveBusiness(business: BusinessModel) {
    return from(this.businessCollection.add(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(business))));
  }
```

You don't need to create another observable in the effect - get rid of "of()", but note the catchError here now has the error:

```
AddBusiness$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(BusinessActions.AddBusiness),
      mergeMap(({ business }) => this.businessService.saveBusiness(business).pipe(
          map(() => BusinessActions.CreateBusinessSuccess()),
          catchError(( error ) => of(BusinessActions.CreateBusinessFailure( error )))
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the job.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome. I also meant to say something about your component, but I forgot. Your component should not be filtering actions$ to display the message. You should a UI effects that listens for this and call the message service directly. Component should not this additional responsibility.

Comment: That makes so much sense,  having the component listen for all these events has caused messy code.  This one is simple, but others have multiple actions; becomes messy.  I will change my code.  Thanks.